# Persisting Object Graph to SQL Server in a single transaction

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I am having an issue coming up with a solution that I think must be a common problem to be solved by anyone writing to a database. I keep thinking that there is an obvious solution that I'm overlooking and that's why I can't find an appropriate existing question here.

Imagine a situation where you need to let a user create a "Class", with "Students", and each "Student" is assigned one or more books. You have a well defined hierarchy, Class->Student->Book.

You have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Classes (
    ClassId int identity(1,1) primary key,
    ClassName nvarchar(255)
    )

CREATE TABLE Students (
    StudentId int identity(1,1) primary key,
    ClassId int,
    StudentName nvarchar(255),
    StudentImage image
    )

CREATE TABLE StudentBooks (
    StudentBookId int identity(1,1) primary key,
    StudentId int,
    BookName nvarchar(255)
    )
```

With this contrived scenario, what are my options for saving this entire graph of new objects, while letting SQL server assign the identity columns, and keeping it all in one transaction? Assuming that a class has maybe 30 students, and each student has several books assigned.

I could create a transaction and make a separate call for each row in each table, returning SCOPE_IDENTITY for each new parent object so I can save each child while keeping RI intact.

I could use XML. I would like to avoid that, as the graph includes a byte array.

Any other options? I thought about passing each level of the hierarchy in a table parameter. I'm not sure how or if that would work. (Wouldn't I have to define a table type for each of my tables, essentially duplicating the schema?)

I can use SQL server 2012 for this.

Thank you!

Comment: Entity Framework already resolves this automatically, and sets the Identity values properly to each object in the graph. Maybe you should consider using an ORM like EF instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Have you already inspected an ORM wrapper? EF is easy to use and does what you want.

Comment: I have! And I am considering using EF. It seems to be unpopular at my work place. This is for a product that's been languishing for years as a LAN only product for a few users at a time. This is the first release that will have potentially millions of rows. So I'm a little worried about performance (though I expect inserts and selects to be similar to what I've characterized above. Touching hundreds of rows at the high end.)

Comment: EF is built to have good performance, at least if you use it right.

Comment: Well...EF it is I guess. Hopefully I can manage to "use it right". :)

Comment: It is really easy. If you get stuck, just let me (or better stackoverflow) know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Entity Framework to achieve what you want.

There are lots of tutorials out there, but a good starting point is this one:

[MSDN on getting started with Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696194%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

or the linked page

[MSDN overview page on getting started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ee712907)

I would recommend the EDMX approach for your use-case.